# jQuery mobile: Inserting new elements doesn't style correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

When inserting new jQuery mobile elements into the page they do not style correctly, even when using `.trigger("create");` on the containing element. This does, however go some way setting the correct styling but falls short.

For instance, when appending like so:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            ...
            $('#results').append("<a href='#' data-role='button'>"+content+"</a>");
        }
        $('#results').trigger("create");
```

The display is like so:

[image]

Notice the extra rounded corners. Whereas if I just include the code on the page it displays correctly like so:

[image]

This same issue is occurring anytime I load anything into the page after the page has loaded. Does anyone know a way around this other than just forcing the styles in a custom stylesheet?

Comment: Can you post a sample to jsbin? What's the version of JQM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Create" event enhances child markup in triggered elements(eg. $('#results')...).

So, you can be solved by replacing

```
$('#results').trigger("create");
```

with

```
$('#results').parent().trigger("create");
```

**[Demo:jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quzYB/)**

Comment: I have to go one step further up the chain to get it to work properly $('#results').parent().parent().trigger("create") but this solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile works on html attributes to style the page, some of this styling involves also adding certain elements to the page (span,div etc.).

Jquery mobile also comes with a CSS that acommodates thos stylings. So, even if you have a quite simple HTML page, if you look at it using firebug or other inspection tool, you'll see that a lot of other elemnts where added dynamically to the page.

If you go and add another element, you need to make sure it fits with the jquery mobile css design. If not, you need to find the class that affects your newly added elemnt (again, using firebug) and either edit the styling in the jquery mobile css, or override it with your stylesheet.